# Copy sheets from another workbook with Bloomberg formulas

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I wrote a simple VBA to copy paste sheet content from another workbook. However, that sheet contains Bloomberg formulas which need to be refreshed before copying. How do I refresh the Bloomberg formulas on the other workbook before copying it to my current workbook, without opening it?

Code is below:

```
Sub foo()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim current_sht1 As Worksheet
Dim FilePath As String
Dim shtName1 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FilePath = Range("Path") & "FILENAME"
shtName1 = "SHEETNAME"

Set current_sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName1)
current_sht1.Cells.Clear

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
Set sht1 = wb.Worksheets(shtName1)

sht1.UsedRange.Copy
current_sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
current_sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Also the file I am working with contains a ton of Bloomberg real time formulas, which is hard to work with during market hour. Is there any way to make the data feed more efficient? And I don't want to uncheck the real time option as we kinda want it to be real time...

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can have the Bloomberg formulae update without opening the workbook. On your 2nd question, trees a setting in Excel to increase the refresh interval.

Comment: Perhaps separate the “ton” of bloomberg formulae into separate workbooks even running on different machines ie in parallel. Then combine the results as or if needed.

Comment: ”Also the file I am working with contains a ton of Bloomberg real time formulas, which is hard to work with during market hour. Is there any way to make the data feed more efficient?”.  One thing people do is put all the real-Time feeds in one sheet, and any calculations involving the feeds in another. Then set Calculation to Manual and hit Shift-F9 on the feed sheet when you need an update, or use Application.OnTime to fire a re-calculate every second (or whatever interval is appropriate). This is what I have done for ‘live’ bootstrapped interest-rate curves.

Answer (score 0):

By your code I assume *sht1* is the sheet with the Bloomberg formulas on it. Do a recalulate of the sheet befory copying like that

```
sht1.Calculate
```

Comment: I've tried this, but still giving "#N/A Requesting Data...". I think it did recalculate the sheet but data came in after copying...